# Rep for account connection not awarded when reaching rep after connection

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, user-accounts, linked-accounts

I have more than 200 rep on meta.SO now, but on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/321973?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top) I wasn't awarded with the [100 bonus](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/new-automatic-account-association/). Do I need to trigger this somehow or is the bonus only awarded if you sign up at the other SOFU-sites *after* having 200 rep on the first one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not have the required +200 in the network at the time of association, you don't get the bonus.

So yes, you need to unassociate and re-associate (or unassociate, log out, and log in)

Answer (score 3):

IIRC, the new auto-association rules say that you should get the bonus automatically. However, try clearing all associations on your accounts page and then log out and then back in, which should trigger an association.